# Add escape character (\n) to last element in tuple of strings

Tags: python

I have a tuple of strings like this:

`stringTuple = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6']`

I later combine this tuple with multiple others and input into an excel document. I need new line break between each of these tuples - so I need it to look like this.

`stringTuple = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6\n']`

I've looked into different sorts of string concatenation such as:
`stringTuple[-1:] = stringTuple[-1:] + '\n'` with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last element in your list is `stringTuple[-1]`.

Add a line break to the last element in your list:

```
stringTuple[-1] = stringTuple[-1] + "\n"
```

Or just:

```
stringTuple[-1] += "\n"
```

---

By the way, `stringTuple[-1:]` is a slice of your array (an interesting read is in another SO question, [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)). `stringTuple[start:]` yields a list of all the items in a list, from index `start` onwards. In this case, `stringTuple[-1:]` is a list of all your items from the last index onwards (i.e. a list of the last item in your original list):

```
stringTuple = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6']

print(stringTuple[-1:]) # ['String6']
```

---

### Making this work with tuples

Tuples are immutable, so you can't make modifications in place (if you want to modify items in a tuple, you actually need to create a new tuple with the modified items in it):

```
stringTuple = ('String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6')

# get last item in tuple, add line break to it
lastItemWithLineBreak = stringTuple[-1] + "\n"

# create a new tuple consisting of every item in our original list but the last
# and then add our new modified item to the end
newTuple = tuple(i for i in stringTuple[:-1]) + (lastItemWithLineBreak,)

print(newTuple) # ('String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6\n')
```

Note the special notation `(lastItemWithLineBreak,)`, which is used to create a tuple consisting of the single element `lastItemWithLineBreak`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works great with a list. The List i have is of type: tuple. Which after running your code produces this error: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Tuples are immutable which means they can't be modified. You'd need to create a new tuple consisting of the items you want to keep plus the new last item

Comment: @babis95 I edited my answer to include an exampe of how to make this work with tuples

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, add end line for last element of tuple:

```
stringTuple[-1] += '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works great with a list. The List i have is of type: tuple. Which after running your code produces this error: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment